# System design to store pieces of data with specific ttyl to then refetch

Tags: multithreading, node.js, mongodb, distributed-system, stream-processing

I have a system which generates pieces of data that needs to be tracked and assigned a specific TTYL value (a value in seconds) for how long they are supposed to live before being re-processed.

I decided to push these messages to **mongo db** and **have a run loop** to find the messages that have expired and are ready to be processed.

[image]

**My concerns:**
The problem with my approach is that I can see situations where too much load would cause messages to potentially be detected and processed by the run loop potentially several minutes later if things are backed up.

**Other considerations**:

- The smallest interval a message can live is 1 second.
- I don't have to use mongodb but I thought it made sense for this use case.
- The throughput could be large anywhere from 1 message per second to 10,000 per second

**My questions**

- Is this the right approach if not which part of the system should I reconsider?

**My attempt**

- I wrote a mongodb query that could potentially find expired messages like so.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I feel mongodb is not a good fit for the use-case you described, since you have to hand-code the scheduler/run-loop and worry about load and throughput. My understanding is that you'll need a delayed message processor. Perhaps RabbitMQ with the [delayed message exchange plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2015/04/16/scheduling-messages-with-rabbitmq/) is a better fit. In short, you can publish the data as a message with ttl (in milliseconds) using the 'x-delay' header. The message will be delivered to your subscribers as soon as the ttl elapses.

Comment: Thanks very much for that input and idea. This does sound like a god idea but any idea if in rabbitmq there is a way to query the queue? Lets say there are times where I want to immediately process all the items even if their ttyl is not over. A piece of information I left out is that each item corresponds to a group_id so there are instances where I would want to immediately process all items for a given group ignoring the ttyl. That's why it became quite complicated. Could rabbitmq somehow be queried like that or maybe combining mongo and rabbit somehow.